# PyCharm - project structure for test & auto-imports

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following project structure:

```
dev
|_app
  |_package
    |_module.py
    |___init__.py
|_tests
  |_test_util.py
  |_module_test·py
  |___init__.py
```

I've got trouble configuring PyCharm project structure so that in the same time:

- tests run properly
- auto-imports work properly

If I set my Content Root to dev then auto-imports work ok, but when I try to run tests which have an import like this:

```
from tests.test_util import SomeUtil
```

I'm getting: ImportError: No module named test_util.

If I set my Content Roots to dev/tests and dev/app then whenever I use auto-import (e.g. Alt+Enter) I end up having:

```
from package import module
```

even though I expected:

```
from app.package import module
```

How do I make PyCharm understand my project structure properly? Defining any folders as sources doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted PyCharm support (very responsive and eager to help I must say). Unchecking "Add Content routes to PYTHONPATH" and "Add Source roots to PYTHONPATH" in my test configurations solved my problem.